# How to use this for killing array of threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

This code worked fine , but how to use it to kill for array of remaining threads?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void *print1(void *tid) 
{
    pthread_t *td= tid;
    pthread_mutex_t lock1=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
    printf("1");
    printf("2");
    printf("3");
    printf("4\n");
    printf("Coming out of thread1 \n");
    sleep(2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
    pthread_kill(*td,SIGKILL);//killing remaining all threads 
    return NULL;
}
void *print2(void *arg) 
{
    pthread_mutex_t *lock = arg;
    pthread_mutex_lock(lock);
    sleep(5);        
    printf("5");
    sleep(5);
    printf("6");
    sleep(5);
    printf("7");
    sleep(5);
    printf("8\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(lock);
    return NULL;
}
int main() 
{
    int s;
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    printf("creating Thread 1and 2 \n");
    sleep(2);
    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, print1,&tid2);
    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, print2,&lock);
    printf("Running Thread 1\n");
    sleep(2);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comments: Please delete this and add some extra information about the code. The editor is not allowing me to edit the code.

Comment: Add some more details to the code. What the code does and what are you expecting?

Comment: Use the stackover flow editor to edit your code. Use 'CTRL+K' key combination to align the code.

Comment: how to add context to code

Comment: can u tell me how u added context

Comment: Select the code and use 'CTRL + K' key combination.

Answer (score 0):

```
here is an edited version of the code
along with some commentary

#include<signal.h>
#include<pthread.h>



void *print1(void *tid)
{
    // should be in global space, so no need to pass
    pthread_t *td= tid; 

    // this is a whole new mutex, 
    //should be in global space so other threads can access it
    pthread_mutex_t lock1=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; 

    // why bother with the mutex, it does nothing useful
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
    printf("1");
    printf("2");
    printf("3");
    printf("4\n");

    printf("Coming out of thread1 \n");
    sleep(2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);

    pthread_kill(*td,SIGKILL);//killing remaining all threads return NULL;

    // this exit is not correct, it should be this call:
    // void pthread_exit(void *rval_ptr);
} // end function: print1


void *print2(void *arg)
{
    // this should be in global memory so all threads using same mutex
    pthread_mutex_t *lock = arg;

    pthread_mutex_lock(lock);
    sleep(5);
    printf("5");
    sleep(5);
    printf("6");
    sleep(5);
    printf("7");
    sleep(5);
    printf("8\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(lock);

    // this exit is not correct, it should be this call:
    // void pthread_exit(void *rval_ptr);      
    return NULL;
} // end function: print2


int main()
{
    int s;

    // this should be in global memory
    // so no need to pass to threads
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;

    pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    printf("creating Thread 1and 2 \n");

    // why bother to sleep here?
    sleep(2);

    // in these calls, the last parm should be NULL
    // and the related data should be in global memory
    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, print1,&tid2);
    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, print2,&lock);

    // we are still in main, so this printf is misleading
    printf("Running Thread 1\n");

    // no need to sleep() 
    // as the pthread_join calls will wait for the related thread to exit
    sleep(2);

    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: here i killed second thread how to kill if we come out of one single threas @user3629249

Comment: pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, print1,&tid2); how to pass array of threads to kill

Comment: im asking a question ur saying improvement?

Answer (score 0):

However you want. There is no "one right way" to do this.

Probably the easiest way is to replace your calls to `sleep` with calls to a function that uses `pthread_cond_timedwait` and a predicate that causes the thread to call `pthread_exit`.

In psuedo-code, replace calls to `sleep` with this logic:

1. Compute the time to sleep until.
2. Lock the mutex.
3. Check if the predicate is set to exit, if so, call `pthread_exit`.
4. Call `pthread_cond_timedwait`.
5. Check if the predicate is set to exit, if so, call `pthread_exit`.
6. Check if the time expired, if not, go to stop 4.

And to terminate the threads, do this:

1. Lock the mutex.
2. Set the predicate to exit.
3. Call `pthread_cond_broadcast`.
4. Release the mutex.
5. Call `pthread_join` on the threads to wait until they've terminated.