# I killed single thread by using following code. How to kill array of threads using this code?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

> ```
>         #include<stdio.h>   
>         #include<signal.h>    
>         #include<pthread.h>
>
>                   void *print1(void *tid)     {
>                    pthread_t *td= tid;//assigning argument to pointer td
>                    pthread_mutex_t lock1=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;//mutex for synchronization
>                 printf("Running Thread 1\n");
>                    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
>                    printf("1");
>
>                    printf("2");
>
>             printf("3");
>
>                    printf("4\n");
>
>             printf("Coming out of thread1\n");
>             sleep(2);
>                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
>
>                pthread_kill(*td,SIGKILL);//or we can use pthread_cancel(*td) killing thread 2 
>             pthread_exit(NULL);
>                   }    void *print2(void *arg)     {
>                   pthread_mutex_t *lock = arg;//acquiring lock
>                   pthread_mutex_lock(lock);
>            sleep(5);   //sleeps for 5 sec     
>            printf("5");
>            sleep(5);//sleeps for 5 sec     
>                   printf("6");
>            sleep(5);//sleeps for 5 sec     
>                   printf("7");
>            sleep(5);//sleeps for 5 sec     
>                   printf("8\n");
>
>                   pthread_mutex_unlock(lock);
>                pthread_exit(NULL);
>               }    int main()     {
>               int s;
>               pthread_t tid1, tid2;//thread id's
>               pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
>               printf("creating Thread 1and 2 \n");
>               sleep(2);
>
>               pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, print1,&tid2);//creating thread1
>               pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, print2,&lock);//creating thread2
>
>               sleep(2);
>
>               pthread_join(tid1, NULL);//joing to execute thread1
>
>
>               pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
>
>
>            return 0;    }
> ```

Comment: please format the code properly.

Comment: any one give me reply

Comment: You've posted 4 questions on the same topic. And if you've still not got any response, it means that you aren't asking the question the right away. Tell us what your code is doing, what have you understood till now, where are you stuck etc. Just posting bunch of code and asking ppl to help will not help

Comment: im already explained with comments     i created two pthreads in c  and then in thread function1 i after executing thread1 i wanna kill thread2 . this thing the above code does

Comment: Now my question is how can i modify this to kill array of threads from any other thread which is in exection

Comment: "I killed single thread" No you didn't. You killed the entire process. `pthread_kill` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: And if you have a question, put it in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: then can we use pthread_cancel(tid); @n.m.

Comment: have you tried it?`pthread_cancel` works but only when the thread being cancelled arrives to a cancellation point. looks like it could work in your case.

Comment: @user1208381 If `pthread_cancel` happens to do what you want, you can use it. But there are a large number of potential gotchas with it and it's much better to learn how to do it other ways first because then you have complete control over everything that happens. If you use a black box you can't see inside, you're more likely to create subtle problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can kill one or more threads using any method you choose. You are writing the code the threads run, so you can code them to terminate under whatever conditions you like. There's no particular restrictions.

Your code doesn't kill one thread, by the way.

> The SIGKILL signal is sent to a process to cause it to terminate immediately (kill). In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, this signal cannot be caught or ignored, and the receiving process cannot perform any clean-up upon receiving this signal. -- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGKILL)

So you told one thread to kill the process, which it did. If you ever feel you need to force a thread to do something, that means you didn't code the thread to do what you wanted it to do in the first place. Instead of trying to kill a thread, code that thread to terminate itself.

Comment: can u post some code of it. which suites my question im asking how to kill array of remaining threads when we come out of any single thread @David Schwartz

Comment: @user1208381 You can use any thread synchronization method you like. You can use a boolean protected by a mutex, for example. You can use a predicate variable, mutex, and condition variable. You can do it any way you like. You are writing the code these threads execute, so you can code it to terminate under whatever conditions you like.

Comment: can u explain with code i tried to kill array of threads but i wont !

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27200647/721269), but honestly I don't see any evidence that you understand any of the issues involved. It seems unlikely that it will be possible to provide an answer to your question that you would be able to understand without learning a lot more about the fundamentals of multithreading.

Comment: i have a little knowledge in this area this work is assigned to me so try to learn these things sorry for wasting ur time i dint get even each word of ur answer IF U WANT TO SUGGGEST ANY SITES OR TUTOS PLSE SHARE

Comment: Start with the basics of how threads cooperate and how they're synchronized. You need to understand how mutexes and condition variables work as well.

Comment: @user1208381 This is not 4chan (actually, even 4chan has etiquette). We generally do not use “u” for “you” or “plz” for “please” here. Your writing looks like you don't care at all. How about you start to write correct English first? People will be more likely to help you if your questions look like you gave them some effort.